# TCP behaving extremely slow and unreliable on Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I am building a simple registration system using `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` classes. For my project, I am using Unity game engine.

My project is separated in 2 applications: client side and server side. When I build the client application for PC, everything works fast and reliable. I run my server application on a PC, and my client application on a laptop (so, 2 completely different machines). I fill-in registration information on my laptop, click "Register" and I get correct feedback from server in a few milliseconds.

However, the problem arises when I built the same client application for Android. Everything is the same as the application that runs on my laptop, but the connection is extremely slow and unreliable (sometimes it doesn't work at all).

For example, I could successfully register from my Android phone (albeit it is not that fast like it is on the laptop), but when I try to register again (establish connection with the server again), it might take 30 seconds or more to connect to the server again.

---

Client side registration:

```
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(address, port))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()) {AutoFlush = true}) {
                writer.BaseStream.WriteByte((byte) ClientRequest.Register);
                writer.WriteLine(usernameInputField.text);
                writer.WriteLine(passwordInputField.text);

                ...
            }
```

Server side listener:

```
    _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
    _listener.Start();

    try {
        while (IsRunning) {
            TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            _clientThreads.Add(new ClientThread(client)); // handle connection in a separate thread
        }
    }
    catch {
        Trace.WriteLine("Server connection closed.");
    }
    finally {
        _listener.Stop();
    }
```

It also might be worth mentioning that I have totally disabled firewall on my PC that runs the server application, as well as required internet connection when doing the Android build.

I really don't see what could be wrong in this code. I mean, there seems to be nothing wrong as it works perfectly well on the PC. But why won't it work on my Android phone as well?

Answer (score 1):

> the connection is extremely slow and unreliable (sometimes it doesn't work at all).

That is the most normal part of developing Mobile apps. Connection is slow, unreliable to outright not working half the time. This is what a App Developer has to deal with, as much as a slow CPU, limited RAM/storage, no rights to write anyhwere or usre a required piece.

As it is a networking to outright hardware issue (literally no tower to connect to), there is nothing you can do here aside from limiting what needs to be send.

Most Mobile apps use a [Distributed Database Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database) to get around it. While the basic idea is not new (IMAP Mail clients were already one), it really became popular with Mobile apps. Exactly because of those connection issues.

Trying to port a PC App to a Mobile Phone was propably the wrong approach. The Mobile World is just way to limited compared to "proper" Computers with "proper" Networking. You usually develop the Mobile App first, then port it to PC/Laptop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I find it hard to believe that there is no simple way to reliably send and receive a few bytes of data from a phone.

Comment: @FICHEKK If you find a 100% reliable connection - no mater the speed - tell the rest of us. We have been looking for one since SMS became a thing. :D As for "a few bytes": How few bytes are that realy? And how much CPU load is there to process/unpack those bytes? How quick is the conneection? Actually wich way is the connection too: Did you connect to the same WLAN, or let the Mobile Phone go out via the Mobile Internet to access your Server through the router?

Comment: This is really the most basic, no security, registration system where the client sends about 20 bytes of data. There is little to non processing on the server side. Everything is connected to the same local network. Connection is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed the problem. The problem was that I was doing networking calls on the main thread. I did not know that this was not allowed on the Android, but it looks like it is the case.

Simply calling the networking code from the new thread fixed the issue:

```
new Thread(() => {
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(address, port))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()) {AutoFlush = true}) {
        writer.BaseStream.WriteByte((byte) ClientRequest.Register);
        writer.WriteLine(usernameInputField.text);
        writer.WriteLine(passwordInputField.text);

        ...
    }
}).Start();
```